# Querying list in a Snowflake VARIANT file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a VARIANT table that has many JSON files but, for the sake of the example and to illustrate my issue, let's look at only the two rows below.

```
{ 
    "id" : "1", 
    "fields":
       [ 
          { 
         "id": "somekey1", 
          "value" : "value1"
            }, 
            { 
            "id": "somekey2", 
         "value" : "value2"
         }
        ]
},
{
    "id" : "2", 
    "fields":
       [ 
          { 
           "id": "somekey1", 
           "value" : "value1"
          }, 
          { 
           "id": "somekey2", 
           "value" : "value2"
          },
          { 
            "id": "somekey3", 
         "value" : "value3"
          }
       ]
}
```

I want to write a query that would give me this output:

| ID | VALUES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["value1","value2","value3"] |
| 2 | ["value1","value2"] |

I have tried many things and this query gave me something of a result but not remotely close to the desired output:

```
 SELECT
      file:id as ID,
      s.value:value::varchar as VALUES
from variant_table,
      table(flatten(FILE:fields)) s
```

And the result is below, plus it omits the JSON if the `fields` is empty:

| ID | VALUES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "value1" |
| 1 | "value2" |
| 1 | "value3" |
| 2 | "value1" |
| 2 | "value2" |

What would be the best approach to solve this in Snowflake?

Comment: In the example, are the two objects in an array in a single row in the table, or are they in two different rows?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's two separate rows

Comment: I think you just need to add a `listagg` or `array_agg` function to aggregate your results after you've flattened them.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks, it works with adding OUTER => TRUE argument. However I encounter a new problem now, and I will edit my question to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After flattening, this will turn the rows into arrays for the VALUES column:

```
 SELECT
      file:id::int as ID,
      array_agg(s.value:value::varchar) as "VALUES"
from variant_table,
      table(flatten(FILE:fields)) s
group by ID
```

Comment: This is the solution for my issue. I would like to add that if in reality there are `fields` that have no value, adding `OUTER => TRUE` argument to `flatten`, prevents omitting those rows and also if there are multiple sources that need to be flattened in the same query, adding `distinct` to `array_agg` prevents creating duplicates.